# What does $\bar{y}$ with a line over it represent?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, notation, statistics

I've been asked to complete this chart and have never come across this symbol before, nor can I find anything about it on google:

[image: data table]

What does the $\bar{y}$ with the line over it represent?
And also, does the the t^2 column just mean square all of the time values for each row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\bar{y}$ means the mean of the $y$ values. For each time value, you want to take the mean of the five $y$ measurements to get a best value.

$t^2$ is just the square of the time. You want to do this because you will be plotting $y$ versus $t^2$. You expect $y \propto t^2$, so plotting that will give you a straight line. You can then fit that straight line to get the proportionality constant.

Answer (score -2):

$\bar x$ is the sum of the $x$ divided by $n$, the sample size. Similarly, $\bar y$ is the sum of the $y$ divided by $n$, the sample size.

i.e.
\begin{align}
x_1=& 5,\, x_2=3,\, x_3= 1 \\
\bar x &=\frac{ 5 + 3 + 1}3 \\
\bar x &= 3
\end{align}